# django - what goes into the form action parameter when view requires a parameter?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

This is what I have:

`myview.py` with a view that takes a parameter `user`:

```
def myview(request, user):
   form = MyForm(request.POST)
   ....
   return render_to_response('template.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The `user` gets passed through an url.

`urls.py`:

```
...

urlpatterns += patterns('myview.views',
    (r'^(?P<user>\w+)/', 'myview'),
)

...
```

I also have a `template.html` with a form:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action=".">
...
</form>
```

What goes in the the form action parameter if `myview` function requires a parameter?

Right now I have `action="."` . The reason I'm asking is because when I fill up the form In (templates.html) and  click the submit button I see absolutely no field values passed from that form. It's almost like I'm passing an empty form when I click the submit button. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are posting to the same view that also serves the form. So at first, the view is called and serves the form. When you post the form, the same view gets called but this time you process the form. That's why the action is empty.

Comment: If that is the case what exactly should I do to avoid it?

Comment: get rid of the dot in action=".". Then the form will be posted to the same view and processed. What are you trying to avoid? If you want to post to a different view, you can put the path in action instead of leaving it empty

Answer (score 36):

If you want to explicitly set the action, assuming you have a variable *username* in your template,

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{% url myview.views username %}">
```

or you could assign a name for the url in your urls.py so you could reference it like this:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('myview.views',
    url(r'^(?P<user>\w+)/', 'myview', name='myurl'), # I can't think of a better name
)

# template.html
<form name="form" method="post" action="{% url myurl username %}">
```

Comment: Using the URL template tag, you need to have the `' '` around the URL as: `{% url 'myurl' parameter_to_pass %}`

Answer (score 7):

It should not require anything.  Assuming you are at the following url:

```
www.yoursite.com/users/johnsmith/
```

Your form should be:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
```

At this point, you are already in `myview` with user `johnsmith`.  Your view should look like the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # you should be able to extract inputs from the form here
else:
    form = MyForm()
```

Comment: Some browsers (e.g. recent Chrome builds) will fail to post if the action attribute is empty.

Comment: @shacker maybe `action="."` is enough to solve the issue with chrome?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `request.path` and that will work in most cases.