# Django login form in header

Tags: django, authentication, pythonanywhere

I have a generic login form that works perfectly using the login module from django.contrib.auth.views

What I am trying to do is have a login dropdown that is visible from the website header (which is included on all pages) if the user is not authenticated. I have the dropdown working correctly if the user is not authenticated, but after filling out the username/password, nothing happens.

I think this example is close, but I can't quite get it to work: [django - what goes into the form action parameter when view requires a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467192/django-what-goes-into-the-form-action-parameter-when-view-requires-a-parameter)

Does the approach of sending the formaction property of the submit button to a different URL seem like the right decision? Is there another preferred method to accomplish this?

```
#relevant form code from the header.html include
<form action="" method="post" class="submission-form">
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p class="error">Sorry, that is not a valid username or password</p>
  {% endif %}
    <label for="username">User name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

    <input type="submit" value="login" action="http://mysite.com/accounts/login/" />{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|escape }}" />
  </form>
```

This code was copied directly from my login page which works correctly.

Let me know of any other pieces of code that will help answer the question.

Comment: The call to the login view is done? the view returns a 200?

Comment: i'm not sure how to check that. I've checked the serverlog, errorlog, and accesslog but do not see anything? There is no sign of anything happening on the front-end. Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: if you are using the `runserver` command, you should see the log of the request from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some feedback here and on [Pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), I've been able to solve this issue.

I had narrowed it down to a problem passing the HTML since the login works correctly on the /accounts/login/ page. I found out that the logging in from the header worked only on the /accounts/login/, but the other pages it did not, so that meant there definitely was a problem passing to the page.

The problem ended up being that I had the input property named "action", when it should have been "formaction". I knew it was really close and it would be something dumb like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with setting your form's `action` property to a URL that is different than the current view being viewed in order to perform your login.

You can always bring the user directly back to the page they were viewing by setting the `next` hidden field in your form to the value of the current URL, then passing that to the built-in login view, or redirect them somewhere else...it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks, glad to see you agree that this seems like an acceptable method. The question now is how to troubleshoot why this submit would not work, when the same form on http://mysite.com/accounts/login/ successfully logs the user in?

Comment: Tests my friend - tests. Set up the conditions you expect and see what's happening. Tests will help you out tremendously to make sure that future code additions and changes don't break your app.